# Big Query copy partition tables within certain range

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Production dataset and Test dataset in BigQuery. Both are partitioned in Days (both have _PARTITIONTIME column).

Is there a way for me to copy Production dataset (using bq cp function) partition tables within a specific range to Test dataset? ex: in the last 1 month.

If I just want to copy 1 partition tables, I would just use the $[yyyymmdd] keyword to select that 1 partition tables, but I am trying to avoid using comma 30 times to select a one month worth of partition tables.

I know querying is possible with something like _PARTITIONTIME >= "2018-01-01 00:00:00" AND _PARTITIONTIME < "2018-01-30 00:00:00".

Is it also possible to do a similar thing for copy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is no.
You can write simple script using bq command to do this doing it one by one.

Or you can generate bq command to do this with something like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  CONCAT('bq cp <srcproj>:<dataset>.<table>$', partname, ' <testproj>:<dataset>.<table>$', partname)
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y%m%d',
      CAST(_PARTITIONDATE AS datetime)) partname
  FROM
    `<srcproj>.<dataset>.<table>`
  WHERE
    _PARTITIONTIME >= "2018-05-10 00:00:00"
    AND _PARTITIONTIME < "2018-05-13 00:00:00")
```

Comment: Ouch.. and I have about 20 tables that I have to copy.. :( I will probably write a simple program just to produce the bash script then..

Comment: I still recommend use query like I gave you to produce list. It will properly handle missing partitions because it building list directly from BQ metadata. So essentially you bash script will just loop via list of 20 tables and dump bq cp commands for everything . Please do not forget to vote answer up if you think it is useful 